# Units or math operations error in kinetic energy of small particles and coefficient of restitution

Tags: python, math

So I've got a graph for kinetic energy of a certain number of particles. I have the code opening the particle files, reading the velocity components, then doing some math to average them.

```
avg = np.array(ys).mean(axis=0)      #averaging
m = 1 * 10**-6                       #in mg
v = avg / 1000                       #in mm/s
KE = 0.5 * m * v * v                 #average kinetic energy
```

then plotting that graph, which I can curve fit too.

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return  a/(1+x/b)**2 # a/(1+x/b)^2
pars, cov = optimize.curve_fit(f=func, xdata=np.nan_to_num(x), ydata=np.nan_to_num(KE), bounds=(-np.inf, np.inf))
stdev = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
```

My main/major equation, the purpose of my work in graphing and calculating variables is:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2jES.png

I decided to code for epsilon by breaking it up into multiple parts (T0 and tau were a & b from curve fitting, respectively).

```
m = 1.0 * 10**-6                   # mass in mg
o = math.pi * (2 * 0.0005)**2      # pi(2R)^2 where Radius in mm || collision crosssection
T0 = float(pars[0])                # KE in Joules
tau = float(pars[1])               # seconds 
n = 140 / (0.020*.020*.010)        # numParticles / volume in mm^3 || number density

first = 1 / (o * n)
first2 = 1 - first
second = math.sqrt(m / 2)
third = 1 / tau
fourth = math.sqrt(T0)

epsilon = first2 * second * (third / fourth)
epsilon = math.sqrt(epsilon)
print epsilon
```

Is epsilon doing the math in the order that? I know I can't just do this like:

```
math.sqrt(1 - (1 / o * n) * math.sqrt(m / 2) * (1 / tau) / math.sqrt(T0))
```

but the resulting epsilon does not match the one I separately calculate (using Desmos and Symbolab). My numbers are consistently off by several orders of magnitude. I expect T0 in the 10^-10 range, tau between 0.5 - 5 (s), and epsilon between 0 - 1. Right now they are 3.8 * 10^-13, 7.8, and 12 respectively. If it's not the equation operations then it's units somewhere but I am trying to investigate all possibilities. Any help or insight appreciated.

Comment: You've mistranslated the equation to code: that subtraction in `first2` should be outside of the multiplications.  In fact, the code that you "know I can't just do this like" appears to be the correct translation.

Comment: Ok, I can see that now actually. There was a domain error at first but I fixed that with abs(). Thank you!